# Yii2 RESTful relational data

Tags: rest, relational-database, yii2

I am having some trouble getting the Yii2 RESTful API returning relational data. I have this working when viewed through the frontend but i am trying to get the same data through the API and its not working the same way.

*Tables*
`country` - PK is population_id
`population` - Foreign Key is country.population_id

I am getting this error:

> { "success": false, "data": { "name": "Invalid Configuration",
>   "message": "The \"query\" property must be an instance of a class that
>   implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.",
>   "code": 0, "type": "yii\base\InvalidConfigException", "file":
>   "C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\data\ActiveDataProvider.php",
>   "line": 100, "stack-trace": [ "#0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\data\BaseDataProvider.php(79):
>   yii\data\ActiveDataProvider->prepareModels()", "#1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\data\BaseDataProvider.php(92):
>   yii\data\BaseDataProvider->prepare()", "#2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\rest\Serializer.php(162):
>   yii\data\BaseDataProvider->getModels()", "#3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\rest\Serializer.php(131):
>   yii\rest\Serializer->serializeDataProvider(Object(yii\data\ActiveDataProvider))",
>   "#4
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\rest\Controller.php(97):
>   yii\rest\Serializer->serialize(Object(yii\data\ActiveDataProvider))",
>   "#5
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\rest\Controller.php(75):
>   yii\rest\Controller->serializeData(Object(yii\data\ActiveDataProvider))",
>   "#6
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Controller.php(153):
>   yii\rest\Controller->afterAction(Object(yii\base\InlineAction),
>   Object(yii\data\ActiveDataProvider))", "#7
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Module.php(455):
>   yii\base\Controller->runAction('index', Array)", "#8
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\web\Application.php(83):
>   yii\base\Module->runAction('v1/country/inde...', Array)", "#9
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\vendor\yiisoft\yii2\base\Application.php(375):
>   yii\web\Application->handleRequest(Object(yii\web\Request))", "#10
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\AdvancedAPI\api\web\index.php(17):
>   yii\base\Application->run()", "#11 {main}" ] } }

model (Country.php):

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\models;
use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Country extends ActiveRecord 
{
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'country';
    }


    public function getCountries()
    {
        //return $this->hasMany(Population::className(), ['population_id' => 'population_id']);
        return $this->hasMany(Country::className(), ['population_id' => 'population_id']);
    }


        public function getPopulationNumber()
    {
        //return $this->hasOne(Country::className(), ['population_id' => 'population_id']);
        return $this->hasOne(Population::className(), ['population_id' => 'population_id']);
    }
}
```

model (Population.php):

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\models;
use \yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Population extends ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'population';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function primaryKey()
    {
        return ['p_id'];
    }

}
```

controller (CountryController.php):

```
<?php

namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use api\modules\v1\models\Country;

class CountryController extends Controller
{

    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = Country::find()->with('countries', 'populationNumber')->all();
        //$query = Country::find();

        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove `all()` part from your query. So the code should be:

```
<?php
namespace api\modules\v1\controllers;

use yii\rest\Controller;
use yii\data\ActiveDataProvider;
use api\modules\v1\models\Country;

class CountryController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $query = Country::find()->with('countries', 'populationNumber');
        //$query = Country::find();

        return new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, so that gives me the results, but how do i now access the "population_number"?

doing `var_dump(new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]));`

results:
`...
public 'modelClass' => string 'api\modules\v1\models\Country' (length=29)
      public 'with' => 
        array (size=2)
          0 => string 'countries' (length=9)
          1 => string 'populationNumber' (length=16)
      public 'asArray' => null
      public 'multiple' => null
`