# Getting error while listing in Yii2

Tags: php, yii2

I am learning Yii2, when I do listing with custom query I am getting error:

> The "query" property must be an instance of a class that implements the QueryInterface e.g. yii\db\Query or its subclasses.

I am getting data from query but when I put in dataprovider it is giving me error. Here is my code:

```
public function search($params) {
    //$query = User::find();
    $query = new \yii\db\Query;
$query = $query->select(['user.*','tbl_region.id','tbl_region.regionName']) 
      ->from('user')
      ->join('LEFT JOIN','tbl_men_reg_info','tbl_men_reg_info.userID = user.id')
          ->join('LEFT JOIN','tbl_women_info','tbl_women_info.userID = user.id')  
          ->join('LEFT JOIN','tbl_region','tbl_men_reg_info.region = tbl_region.id');
    $command = $query->createCommand();
$query = $command->queryAll();
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
    ]);
    return $dataProvider;
}
```

Can anyone please tell me how to do listing with custom query?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Yii2 RESTful relational data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28122559/yii2-restful-relational-data)

Comment: @Armfoot Yes, it's kind of similar except of data provider usage.

Answer (score 1):

The error is kind of clear, you need to pass instance of `yii\db\Query` to data provider, so remove these lines:

```
$command = $query->createCommand();
$query = $command->queryAll();
```

and it should work.

Note that you also need to use `SqlDataProvider` instead of `ActiveDataProvider`, since models are not involved.

Also modifying variable with different type and meaning is considered bad practice:

```
$query = $command->queryAll();
```

It's not `$query` at this point, it's better to rename it for example as `$rows` or `$results`.